# How to calculate the right-most digits of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n k!$

Tags: factorial, divergent-series, computational-mathematics, binary

Consider the the sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n k!$. Note that for any base $b$, as $k$ increases, the base-$b$ expansion of $k!$ will have a monotonically increasing  number of right-most zeroes.
Hence, the right-most digits of $S_n$ converge as $n\to\infty$.

Take for example the following table of $n$ and the 10 right-most digits of $S_n$ in binary.

```
 n -> right-most 10 digits of S_n
 ================
 0 -> 1
 1 -> 10
 2 -> 100
 3 -> 1010
 4 -> 100010
 5 -> 10011010
 6 -> 1101101010
 7 -> 1100011010
 8 -> 0010011010
 9 -> 1000011010
 10 -> 0100011010
 11 -> 1000011010
 12 -> 1000011010
 13 -> 1000011010
```

Evidently, the right-most 10 digits converge to $1000011010$. This can be shown easily by proving that $k!>2^9$ for all $k>11$.

Regardless, I'd like to calculate an arbitrary amount of these converging right-most digits (particularly in binary). However, as you know, the factorials grow extremely rapidly, blowing past 32 or even 64 bits very quickly, so directly computing the sum of factorials to ridiculous precision in a timely manner is out of the question. Hence, perhaps this is more of a computer-science question, but **what are some mathematical optimizations I can make to calculate these digits without having to calculate each factorial?**

In other words, how would I find the right-most digits of $S_n$ for very large values of $n$? I imagine modular arithmetic may come in handy, although I'm not sure how.

Comment: How much right digits?

Comment: As you suspected, if you want the last $k$ digits of $S_n$ in binary, you need to compute the factorials up to $(2k)!$ (actually, this is a large estimation, it is usually much smaller) modulo $2^{k-1}$. This can actually be done very efficiently, with $k$ operation (sum) by iteration, totalling at most $2k^2$ operations

Comment: @kingW3 Theoretically, an arbitrary amount. Realistically, I can't imagine I'd find a use for knowing more than 1000.

Comment: actually, since you have to compute it only up to $S_{2k}$ (the rest are equal), you need at most $\log_2(2k)$ sums by iteration, meaning $2k\log_2(2k)$ in total

Comment: You have $1050! \equiv 0\mod 2^{1000}$ so to find the last $1000$ right most digits you just have to compute each factorial upto 1050 (you can get a slightly smaller number that is divisible by $2^{1000} $ but I'm lazy to find it rn) $\mod 2^{1000}$, so basically you'd have to use 1000 bits and it shouldn't take more than few miliseconds assuming you have a big number library.

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks for the insight, that worked like a charm. I honestly did not expect computing the sum of the first $1050$ factorials with $1000$ bit precision would take such little time.

Comment: Multiplying two numbers the naive method is basically $O(ab) $ where $a, b$ are the number of bits, and our computers multiply two $64$ bit in one operation so realistically the complexity of multiplying a $1000$ digit number with a $3$ digit number basically is more in line with $17$ operations times $1000$ basically $17000$ operations which is pretty small.

Comment: Here's a live [Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjtEKwjAMRd_3FZeJ0M4J28SXQsH_EJW5tRC062jr_9vWuQUCuSe5SbSzBhSUC9a-PcjM1gUM9jOF4kJTbPRDKEal8WCj7M5cFIhhINE29zELnwQOObtMdCRLZR0INP1WstPi_w8xjQrEsYdZOenUkmi20RRPp_rXStJN5uNBvZlnFx9mvo4Ls94tpPLBMc-vQhzbWw2vZlnWKPkXzQ48iA==&lang=sage) that's pretty fast. Also see [A025016](https://oeis.org/A025016)